# Missing a href in next.js link

Tags: next.js

When I wrap my text into `Link` I am missing `<a href` in dom (but link is working).

It is good for seo? How seo robot know that there is a link?

```
import Link from 'next/link'
.
.
.
<Link href="/about">
  About us
</Link>
```

Dom in browser:

```
About us
```

Excepted dom in browser (from my side):

```
<a href='/about'>
About us
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `a` tag. From [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link):

```js
import Link from 'next/link'

function Home() {
  return (
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link href="/">
          <a>Home</a>
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link href="/about">
          <a>About Us</a>
        </Link>
      </li>
    </ul>
  )
}

export default Home
```